# Python choose COM port with simple GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, customtkinter

I am trying to programm a simple python GUI with customTkinter. How can I use `choice` in `arduino = serial.Serial(port=choice, baudrate=115200, timeout=.1`? Here is my full code:

```
import customtkinter
import serial.tools.list_ports
import serial

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("System")  # Modes: system (default), light, dark
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")  # Themes: blue (default), dark-blue, green

app = customtkinter.CTk()  # create CTk window like you do with the Tk window
app.geometry("400x240")

#list all available ports
available_ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
serial_ports = []
for port in available_ports:
    serial_ports.append(port.device)

def optionmenu_callback(choice):
    print("optionmenu dropdown clicked:", choice)

optionmenu = customtkinter.CTkOptionMenu(app, values=serial_ports, command=optionmenu_callback)
optionmenu.set("COM1")

optionmenu.place(x=30, y=30)

arduino = serial.Serial(port=choice, baudrate=115200, timeout=.1)

arduino.close()
app.mainloop()
```

I want to open a serial connection to an Arduino, so that I can controll it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to create a `serial.Serial` object before you start `app.mainloop()`, which doesn't make any sense: at this point, there UI hasn't been displayed so there has been no opportunity for someone to select a port.

If you're just trying to prompt for a serial port with a UI and then continue with a text-mode program, you could do something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
import serial.tools.list_ports
import serial

class SerialApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("400x240")
        self.selected_port = None
        self.selected_port_var = tk.StringVar(self)

    def refresh_serial_port_list(self):
        self._available_ports = [port.device for port in serial.tools.list_ports.comports()]

    def select_serial_port(self):
        self.refresh_serial_port_list()
        optionmenu = tk.OptionMenu(self, self.selected_port_var, *self._available_ports)
        optionmenu.pack()

        select_button = tk.Button(self, text="Select", command=self.set_port)
        select_button.pack()

        self.mainloop()

    def set_port(self):
        self.selected_port = self.selected_port_var.get()
        self.destroy()

app = SerialApp()
app.select_serial_port()

print('Selected port:', app.selected_port)
```

This will provide your selection dialog, allow the user to select a port, and then shut down the UI (with the selected port available in `app.selected_port`).

If you want to do something different -- e.g., if you're trying to write some sort of interactive serial UI -- you'll need to restructure things.